# Divide a square into rectangles where each occurs once in each orientation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, tiling

A $26 \times 26$ square divides into different rectangles so that each occurs exactly twice in different orientations.

[image: twice used rectangles]

I've also found a solution for the $10 \times 10$ square, but no others.  Are there any other squares that can be divided into a finite number of rectangles so that each occurs exactly twice in different orientations?

Comment: Do you mean that you have ruled it out for squares of length less than 26,  unequal to 10?

Comment: I haven't ruled out anything yet.  My solving programs are geared for the [Mondrian Art Problem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MondrianArtProblem/) at the moment, and I need to loosen some parameters to be sure about anything on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are all rectangles with area 2 through 13, both orientations of those that are not square, in a 17x17. Not quite what you requested since I left the squares in.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the following tiling of $8 \times 8$ square:
`11111222
11111222
11111222
55557222
64497222
64493333
64493333
64400088`

Each digit indicates number of rectangle the cell belongs to.
From 0 to 9 the sizes are: $3 \times 1$, $3 \times 5$, $5 \times 3$, $4 \times 2$, $2 \times 4$, $4 \times 1$, $1 \times 4$, $1 \times 2$, $2 \times 1$, $1 \times 3$.